# How to add this specific type of data into MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I tried to turn it into a json array and parse the json string into MySQL as that made the most sense to me. Plus I already managed to turn it into a json string using:

```
 JSON.stringify(res);
```

Is this the right method? How can I add the x, y, widht, and height into MySQL? I think the problem is that I cant get the Javascript variable to be read in the PHP script.

```
 $('#save').click(function(){
      var res = _.map($('.grid-stack .grid-stack-item:visible'), function (el) {
el = $(el);
var node = el.data('_gridstack_node');
return {
    id: el.attr('data-custom-id'),
    x: node.x,
    y: node.y,
    width: node.width,
    height: node.height
};
});
window.location.href = "index.php?name=" + JSON.stringify(res);
<?php


if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "grids");

 $jsondata = $_GET['name'] ;

 $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

 $x = $data['x'];
 $y = $data['y'];
 $width = $data['width'];
 $height = $data['height'];

 foreach($data as $row){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO new(x, y, width, height) VALUES('".$row[$x]."', '".$row[$y]."', '".$row[$width]."', '".$row[$height]."')";
 mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 }
}

?>
});
```

Comment: is this all in `index.php`? if so then you're sending the JSON as `name=` but reading it as `work`. You should also use prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry, in my code it was all called 'name'. Will using prepared statements fix my erros?

Comment: It would fix any unescaped parameter related errors (e.g. if there are quotes in any of those parameters). It will also protect you from automated SQL injection attacks. You probably also need to `encodeURI(JSON.stringify(res))` for it to be passed to PHP correctly. Also did you mean to include the redirect inside the `click` event?

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong single quotes doube quotes sequnce and don't build a correct string concatenation ..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO new(x, y, width, height) VALUES('" .$row[$x]. 
      "', '" .$row[$y]."', '".$row[$width]. "', '".$row[$height]."')";
```

be aware for sqlinjection  using vars in this way  .. you shoul use a proper parametrized  sql prepare

Comment: Fixed it, still doesnt update the MySQL table. The console says I have this error: unreachable code after return statement. It's reffering to this: 
 window.location.href = "index.php?name=" + JSON.stringify(res);

Comment: You have return in javascript  .. this end  the function .. .. Is not possible run the code after the return .. you have a wrong logic in your code  ..

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I made changes and still nothing. I updated my code above, is the logic in my code correct now?

Comment: I don't know what you really are trying to do ..  at a first look seems that you have mixed  client and server code ..  in the same  .. remember that  the two part are performed  in  different time and in different place..  you should devide you client  code  in a source  fand the server code in another ...